# Error executing a servlet from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I wrote a servlet on eclipse and when i tried to execute it the server gives me the below posted page.

To note: yesterday I executed the same servlet normally i could see the output, but when I tried to run it today i could not. I have not changed any thing every thing is the same.[image]

Comment: That means it can not find it.  Do you need to deploy it again?

Comment: Can you post the web.xml configuration (servlet definition and mapping) ?

Comment: where can i find web.xml

Comment: Try refreshing your project, cleaning and rebuilding your project and maybe even cleaning the server resources. If that doesn't do it check if you have any errors in the console?

Comment: You can find web.xml under Webroot --> Web -INF folder in your project. Please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The status code 404 means that the page is not be found, maybe you updated something in the web.xml file.

You should post contain of your web.xml file here, so that we can see the problem; or you can post the errors from log file if any.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the server and try it.
If it doesnt work then try correcting the web.xml